# Java: toss each dice individually using three dice objects

Tags: java

**Three dice objects and toss each one**. The results of the **toss** should be displayed in an output window. I'm working on this exercise from my previous worked exercise *(PS. reused this code to toss each one dice)*. I've two classes: App and Dice classes. Dice class is fine.

- I've three dice objects already set up and it worked see a **screengrab** as below.
- I'm trying to work out **toss each one** dice in class App.
- You can see a **screengrab** of a result as below but not as toss each one?
- I would appreciate if you (an expert) to show me how to get a toss each one dice, please?

Edited:
This post are linked with the other post:m https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878070/alternative-dice-toss-technique The different in this question is to break down my tried and tested code [of 3 dice tossed at the same time from previous post] to toss a dice once three times individually.

**class App as below - FULL CLass App code - updated**

```
import javabook.*;

class App
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
    App thisProgram = new App();    

}   
    //outside a main class
    public App()
    {

        //contsructor
        //Dice aDice


        //set variables
        //int anDice = 0;
        //int faceValue;

        //Declare objects
        Dice diceOne;       
        Dice diceTwo;       
        Dice diceThree;

        int aNumber = 0;
        int numThrown = 0;
        //while(numThrown < 4)      //UPDATED - commented out
        //int afaceValue;

        //declare objects
        MainWindow mWindow;
        //Dice aDice;           //UPDATED - commented out
        InputBox iBox;
        OutputBox oBox;

        //create objects                
        mWindow = new MainWindow(); 
        //aDice = new Dice();       //UPDATED - commented out       
        iBox = new InputBox(mWindow);   
        oBox = new OutputBox(mWindow);  

        diceOne     = new Dice();       
        diceTwo     = new Dice();
        diceThree   = new Dice();

        //Use objects
        mWindow.show();
        oBox.show();

        while(numThrown < 3) //<4
    {
            Dice dice = new Dice();
        aNumber = iBox.getInteger("Enter 1 to throw the dice, or 0 to exit: ");
        if(aNumber == 1)
            {
                dice.throwDice();
                int rollledNum = dice.getFaceValue();
                oBox.println( "You threw : " + dice.getFaceValue() );
            } 
        else
            {
        return;
            }

        numThrown++;
            }
    }
}
```

**Screengrab of a result as below**
Updated Screen grab below using code as above:
[image]

[image: This is what it look like - previously]

**class Dice as below** This is okay.

```
class Dice
{
    //public static void main(String args[])


    //data
    //private constants
    final int NUMBER_OF_SIDES = 6;

    //private variables
    private int faceValue;

    //constructors
    public Dice()
    {
        this.faceValue = 0;     //zero if not thrown.
    }

    //methods - behavious
    public void throwDice()
    {
        this.faceValue = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * NUMBER_OF_SIDES);
    }

    //method - get (accessors) and sets (mutators)
    public int getFaceValue()
    {
        return(this.faceValue);
    }   
}
```

Comment: "how to get a toss each one dice?", could you elaborate on what you mean by this? 

You are tossing "each" Dice object, currently, as your code stands.

Comment: So it is correct approach? So I must be working too hard then.

Comment: You do it here. 

 diceOne.throwDice();
 diceTwo.throwDice();
 diceThree.throwDice();

Comment: Ok. I ran the terminal again. I see each toss (of three dices) happened at the same time rather than one (dice) toss at a time in the Output window from user input?

Comment: What do you mean by happening at the same time ? You are not using threads so this is all taking place sequentially.

Comment: See screengrab as above: I press enter 1 and press Ok. You threw : 6, You threw : 5, You threw : 5 ====== The numbers is 665. All appeared at the same time. Is it possible to roll dice one at a time with use existing code as above.

Comment: I've tried @a_schimpf code as below and it threw errors, it was worked until a_schimpf have changed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int aNumber = 0;
int numThrown = 0;
Dice dice = new Dice();
while(numThrown < 3)
{
    aNumber = iBox.getInteger("Enter 1 to throw the dice, or 0 to exit: ");
    if(aNumber == 1)
    {
        dice.throwDice();
        int rollledNum = dice.getFaceValue();
        oBox.println( "You threw : " + dice.getFaceValue() );
    } 
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    numThrown++;
}
```

Comment: while dicesThrown<=3 would be better.

Comment: yeah i was a little confused on what was needed. so, this worked for whatever case.

Comment: It worked. It doens't stop after three throws? Including a reminder of oBox.println("The numbers is " + diceOne.getFaceValue() + " " + diceTwo.getFaceValue() + " " + diceThree.getFaceValue() );

Comment: @arynaq .where so I add this: while dicesThrown<=3

Comment: Can you explain this so I know how to use it: while(numThrown < 4)

Comment: There is no need to make a new Dice object every loop through. Additionally, int rollledNum is not used.

Comment: @a_schimpf. Can you go back to the other code before you've changed the above, because it worked better. I didn't have a copy (I wasn't quick enough). Perhaps another grey box as above?

Comment: what do you mean "better"? does this code have an error or does it not run correctly?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. It was shown an error. I've posted a full code as above for your convenience. A previous code you've posted worked better but it doesn't stop after 3 dice throw.

Comment: This is 3 errors: App.java:41: not a statement
  MainWindow mWindow;
  ^
App.java:41: ';' expected
  MainWindow mWindow;
            ^
App.java:41: not a statement
  MainWindow mWindow;

Comment: you added this line for some reason: 'while(numThrown < 4)' before 'MainWindow mWindow;' that is causing the error. take that line out.

Comment: Thank you. I've done that. Now another 3 errors: App.java:67: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable dice
location: class App
           dice.throwDice();
           ^
App.java:68: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable dice
location: class App
           int rollledNum = dice.getFaceValue();
                            ^
App.java:69: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable dice
location: class App
           oBox.println( "You threw : " + dice.getFaceValue() );

Comment: im sorry but your code is so screwed up. i dont even know what youre doing anymore. do you even understand what the code is doing? you should really try to understand the basics of variables and loops first.

Comment: I understand what you're saying @a_schimpf. It worked now. I just commented out Dice aDice; and aDice = new Dice(); with updated code as above. See new screen grab.

Comment: It stopped after 4 throws instead of 3 throws.

Comment: Its tough love. I've changed to while(numThrown < 3) and stopped after 3 toss. That is what I'm looking for. Thank you @a_schimpf for your help earlier. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why did you use if(aNumber == 1) so I will understand better?

Comment: Because by your requirements you want to roll dice if the user inputs one..... any other number will result in exiting the loop (and the application, if you have any code after the loop).

Answer (score 1):

This will allow you to roll dice one at a time (and more then three dice, if you want.)

```
 Dice dice = new Dice(); // 1 dice for all rolls.

while(true){

        aNumber = iBox.getInteger("Enter 1 to throw the dice, or 0 to exit: ");
        if(aNumber == 0){
           break; // bust out of the loop if user enters 0.
         }
        dice.throwDice();
        oBox.println( "You threw : " + dice.getFaceValue() );


    }
```

Comment: The above with compiling errors: App.java:66: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable dice
location: class App
        dice.throwDice();
        ^
App.java:67: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable dice
location: class App
        oBox.println( "You threw : " + dice.getFaceValue() );
                                       ^
Note: App.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

Comment: Did you forget  Dice dice = new Dice(); at the top?